# Fields become empty when adding using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

Hi im trying to create a page that allows more fields to be added.

I have got it to add new fields to the page but they clear. I need it to save on a loop and cant seem to get my head round the logic.

any help would be appriciated heres my code so far.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){

    $(".datepicker").live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num=0;
function addField(){
    num++;
    if(num>14){num--;}
    makefields();
}
function rmField(){
    num--;
    if(num<0){num++;}
    makefields();
}

function makefields(){
var fields="";
for(var o=0;o<=num;o++){
fields+="<p><label>Ingredients</label><input name=\"txtingredient"+o+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\"/>";
fields+="<label>Quantity:</label><input name=\"txtqty"+o+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\" /> or / ";
fields+="<label>Weight</label><input name=\"txtweight"+o+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\" /></p>";
}
fields+="<br/><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"num\" value=\""+o+"\"/>";
if(num!=14){fields+="<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"addField()\">Add</button>";}
if(num>0){fields+="<button type=\"button\" onclick=\"rmField()\">Remove</button>";}
fields+="<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Add recipe\"/></form>";
    document.getElementById("fields").innerHTML=fields;
}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_us.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="frmaddservice" action="add-recipe.php" method="post" class="jNice" onsubmit="return checkaddservice();">
<fieldset>
    <p>
      <label>Recipe Name:</label>
      <input name="txtname" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtname" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Discription:</label>
      <input name="txtdetails" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtdetails" />
    </p>        
    <p>
      <label>Cat:</label>
      <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option>Select Type</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div id="fields">
    <p><label></label>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label>Ingredient </label>
    <input name="txtingredient0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtingredient0" />
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input name="txtqty0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtqty0"/> 
    or /
    <label>Weight</label>
    <input name="txtweight0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtweight0" />
    </p>       
    <p><label></label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="1"/><a href="#" onclick="addField()">Add ingredient</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
    </div><label></label>>
</fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the field are cleared, is because you are adding the field using innerHTML. The previous contents are replace by the new elements you stored. If you have knowledge with JQuery, this will be more easy. Anyway here's the sample working code, just take a look on the changes.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){

    $(".datepicker").live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num=0;
var fieldCount = 1;
function addField(){
    makefields(fieldCount++);
}
function rmField(fieldId){
    var remThis = document.getElementById(fieldId);
    remThis.parentNode.removeChild(remThis);

}

function makefields(){
var fields="";
fields+="<p><label>Ingredients</label><input name=\"txtingredient"+fieldCount+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\"/>";
fields+="<label>Quantity:</label><input name=\"txtqty"+fieldCount+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\" /> or / ";
fields+="<label>Weight</label><input name=\"txtweight"+fieldCount+"\" type=\"text\" class=\"text-long\" />";
fields+='<input type="button" value="remove" onClick="rmField(\'fieldCnt'+fieldCount+'\')" /></p>';
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.innerHTML = fields;
newDiv.setAttribute('id', 'fieldCnt' + fieldCount);
document.getElementById('fieldContainer').appendChild(newDiv);
}

</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_us.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="frmaddservice" action="add-recipe.php" method="post" class="jNice" onsubmit="return checkaddservice();">
<fieldset>
    <p>
      <label>Recipe Name:</label>
      <input name="txtname" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtname" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Discription:</label>
      <input name="txtdetails" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtdetails" />
    </p>        
    <p>
      <label>Cat:</label>
      <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option>Select Type</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div id="fields">
    <p><label></label>
    </p>
    <div id="fieldContainer">
    <div id="fieldCnt1">
    <p>
    <label>Ingredient </label>
    <input name="txtingredient0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtingredient0" />
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input name="txtqty0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtqty0"/> 
    or /
    <label>Weight</label>
    <input name="txtweight0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtweight0" />
    <input type="button" value="remove" onClick="rmField('fieldCnt1')" />
    </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    <p><label></label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="1"/><a href="#" onclick="addField()">Add ingredient</a>
    <input type="button" value="Add Ingredient" onClick="addField()"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
    </div><label></label>>
</fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few issues.

Have a look at this. Note the return false and that I use jQuery to change the data

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.11/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(function(){

    $(".datepicker").live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({showOn:'focus'}).focus();
    });
    });
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var num=0;
function addField(){
    num++;
    if(num>14){num--;}
    makefields();
    return false;
}
function rmField(){
    num--;
    if(num<0){num++;}
    makefields();
}

function makefields(){
var fields="";
for(var o=0;o<=num;o++){
  fields+='<p><label>Ingredients</label><input name="txtingredient'+o+'" type="text" class="text-long"/>';
  fields+='<label>Quantity:</label><input name="txtqty'+o+'" type="text" class="text-long" /> or ';
  fields+='<label>Weight</label><input name="txtweight'+o+'" type="text" class="text-long" /></p>';
}
fields+='<br/><input type="hidden" name="num" value="'+o+'"/>';
if(num!=14){fields+='<button type="button" onclick="addField()">Add</button>';}
if(num>0){fields+='<button type="button" onclick="rmField()">Remove</button>';}
fields+='<input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>';

    $("#fields").append(fields);
}
function checkaddservice(){ return false}
</script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="calendar_us.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form name="frmaddservice" action="add-recipe.php" method="post" class="jNice" onsubmit="return checkaddservice();">
<fieldset>
    <p>
      <label>Recipe Name:</label>
      <input name="txtname" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtname" />
    </p>
    <p>
      <label>Discription:</label>
      <input name="txtdetails" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtdetails" />
    </p>        
    <p>
      <label>Cat:</label>
      <select name="cat" id="cat">
        <option>Select Type</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <div id="fields">
    <p>
    <label>Ingredient </label>
    <input name="txtingredient0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtingredient0" />
    <label>Quantity:</label>
    <input name="txtqty0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtqty0"/> 
    or /
    <label>Weight</label>
    <input name="txtweight0" type="text" class="text-long" id="txtweight0" />
    </p>       
    <p><label></label>
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="num" value="1"/><a href="#" onclick="return addField()">Add ingredient</a>
    <input type="submit" value="Add recipe"/>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi mplugjan, I looked at that and i have tred a simular method of appeding the fields<div> and it creates multips of everything.

Comment: So you need to define what you want to create. I cannot help you there. that is your decision.